# create columns using window-approach in data.frame r

Tags: r, tidyverse

I will try to explain what I want to get. We have data from some individuals, these individuals belong to a longitudinal study and they have visit the doctor several times. The number of visits changes for every patient, the range goes from 2 up to 7 visits. The time between visits is 24 months, i.e, from visit 1 to visit 2 there are 24 months and from visit 2 to visit 4 48 months.
We need to calculate whether some individuals are considered as fast-progressors or not. The criteria to include a individual as fast-progressor are the following:

1. If the individual changes from a Grade (`Grade` column in the data.frame) 0 or 1 to a Grade >=3 in a 48 months window, it could be considered as fast-progressor.
2. If the individual changes from a Grade 0 or 1 to a Grade 2 in a 48 months window is considered as No-rapid-progressor
3. If the individual does not change the Grade in a 48-months window, is considered as No-progressor.

Because we don't have the months and only the visits, we use a 2 visit interval (or just 1 if the individual has only 2 visits) to calculate the progression.

Here is the code we are using, and some dummy data:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Read data
samples2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
  Grade=c(0,1,1,1,3,2,4,4,4,0,3,1,1,1,3,3),
  Visit=c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,5))


# Get the difference between visits using lead from tydiverse
data_window <- samples2 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(basal0_2=ifelse(Grade == 0, lead(Grade, 2) - Grade, 0), # this calculates differences when Grade is 0 and individual has more than 2 visits
         basal1_2=ifelse(Grade == 1, lead(Grade, 2) - Grade, 0), # this calculates differences when Grade is 1 and individual has more than 2 visits
         basal0_1=ifelse(Grade == 0, lead(Grade, 1) - Grade, 0), # this calculates differences when Grade is 0 and individual has only 2 visits
         basal1_1=ifelse(Grade == 1, lead(Grade, 1) - Grade, 0) # this calculates differences when Grade is 1 and individual has only 2 visits
)

# Identify Progressors
# Here we assign Progressor type based on the differences obtained in the previous step.
data2 <- data_window %>% mutate(progression = case_when(basal1_2 == 1 | basal0_2 == 2  ~ 'No_rapid_Progressor', 
                                                        basal1_2 >= 2 | basal0_2 >= 3 ~ 'Rapid_Progressor',
                                                        basal1_1 == 1 | basal0_1 == 2  ~ 'No_rapid_Progressor', 
                                                        basal1_1 >= 2 | basal0_1 >= 3 ~ 'Rapid_Progressor',
                                                        TRUE ~ 'No_Progressor'))
```

My question: is there any other way of doing it without creating dummy variables from "between visit differences" when individual has 2 visits and when individual has more than 2 visits? and also, is any other way more efficient (efficient meaning less lines of code) of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the function of `ID`?

Comment: `ID` means individual, they are individual identifiers

Comment: But why does the progressor changes per `ID`?

Comment: I will try to give you an example: Each individual (`ID`) goes to a clinic several times (`Visit`) and in each visit an examination is taken. So an Individual (`ID 1`) could have a `Grade` 1 in `Visit` 1 and change to 3 in `Visit` 2. So, this individual would be a Rapid Progressor because in a period of 48 months (time between visits is 24 months) his grade changed from 1 to 3.

Comment: For ID 5, why dos your answer have NO progressor, Rapid Progresssor? Its the same person. Should it not just be No progressor because did not change to >=3 within the first 48 months?

Comment: @onyambu, it is NO progressor, and then Rapid Progressor because the code identifies if `Grade` changes in a 48 months window, it hasn't to be the the first 48 months, is a change in a 48 months window

Comment: Why do you have ID2 as rapid progressor from the very beginning? In the first 48 months, ie 1&2 they did not change to a value greater than 3

Comment: @onyambu, the code I am using uses `lead` and this function evaluates the next visit (`Grade == 0, lead(Grade, 1)`, i.e, 12 months or the next 2 visits `(Grade == 0, lead(Grade, 2)`, i.e, 48 months. Because `lead` function moves forward, the individual is annotated as Rapid Progressor in the inmediate visit before Rapid Progression.

Comment: So should that be right? ie should it not be No progressor THEN rapid progressor rather than Rapid progressor THEN no progressor?

Comment: And I have to use `Grade == 0, lead(Grade, 1)` because if I only use `Grade == 0, lead(Grade, 2)` and the individual changes `Grade` in a period of 24months it is not calculated correctly

Comment: in the specific case of Individual 5, it is No progressor, then rapid progressor, rapid progressor,  progressor, no progressor because from visit 2 to visit 4 (48 months window it changes from grade 1 to 3) and from visit 3 to visit 5 (48 months periods) also has a change of (48 months) and then from visit 3 to 4 (24 months period) also changes from 1 to 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using slider which handles partial windows:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

samples2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
                       Grade=c(0,1,1,1,3,2,4,4,4,0,3,1,1,1,3,3),
                       Visit=c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,5))

samples2 |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  mutate(end_window = slide_dbl(Grade, last, .after = 2),
         progression = case_when(
           Grade <= 1 & end_window >= 3 ~ "Rapid_Progressor",
           Grade <= 1 & end_window == 2 ~ "No_rapid_Progressor",
           TRUE                         ~ "No_Progressor"
         ))


#> # A tibble: 16 × 5
#> # Groups:   ID [5]
#>       ID Grade Visit end_window progression     
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>           
#>  1     1     0     1          1 No_Progressor   
#>  2     1     1     2          1 No_Progressor   
#>  3     2     1     1          3 Rapid_Progressor
#>  4     2     1     2          3 Rapid_Progressor
#>  5     2     3     3          3 No_Progressor   
#>  6     3     2     1          4 No_Progressor   
#>  7     3     4     2          4 No_Progressor   
#>  8     3     4     3          4 No_Progressor   
#>  9     3     4     4          4 No_Progressor   
#> 10     4     0     1          3 Rapid_Progressor
#> 11     4     3     2          3 No_Progressor   
#> 12     5     1     1          1 No_Progressor   
#> 13     5     1     2          3 Rapid_Progressor
#> 14     5     1     3          3 Rapid_Progressor
#> 15     5     3     4          3 No_Progressor   
#> 16     5     3     5          3 No_Progressor
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand why the dummies calculate the difference between the current Grade and the next visit or next 2 visits (`lead(Grade, 1) - Grade` and `lead(Grade, 2) - Grade`), but I think I figured out how to clean up the code by using the conditions that you presented.

One thing that I assumed from your dummies is that the conditions not only apply for the timeframe of 48 months, but also for the 24 months, is that correct?

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Read data - the same provided sample
samples2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
  Grade=c(0,1,1,1,3,2,4,4,4,0,3,1,1,1,3,3),
  Visit=c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,5))

# New code to identify the progressors
data2 <- samples2 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(progression = case_when(
    # current Grade equals to 0 or 1 and
    (Grade == 0 | Grade == 1) & 
      # next visit or next 2 visits are equal or greater than 3
      (lead(Grade, 1) >= 3 | lead(Grade, 2) >= 3) 
        ~ "Rapid_progressor", 
    # current Grade equals to 0 or 1 and
    (Grade == 0 | Grade == 1) & 
      # next visit or next 2 visits are equal to 2
      (lead(Grade, 2) == 2 | lead(Grade, 1) == 2) 
        ~ "No_rapid_progressor",
    TRUE ~ "No_progressor"
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(
  lapply(split(setDT(samples2), by = "ID"), function(x) {
    x[, progression := "No-progressor"]
    x[Grade %in% 0:1 & (shift(Grade, n = 1, type = "lead") >= 3 | (shift(Grade, n = 2, type = "lead") >= 3)),
             progression := "Rapid_Progressor"]
    x[Grade %in% 0:1 & (shift(Grade, n = 1, type = "lead") == 2 | (shift(Grade, n = 2, type = "lead") == 2)),
             progression := "No-rapid_Progressor"]
  }))

    ID Grade Visit      progression
 1:  1     0     1    No-progressor
 2:  1     1     2    No-progressor
 3:  2     1     1 Rapid_Progressor
 4:  2     1     2 Rapid_Progressor
 5:  2     3     3    No-progressor
 6:  3     2     1    No-progressor
 7:  3     4     2    No-progressor
 8:  3     4     3    No-progressor
 9:  3     4     4    No-progressor
10:  4     0     1 Rapid_Progressor
11:  4     3     2    No-progressor
12:  5     1     1    No-progressor
13:  5     1     2 Rapid_Progressor
14:  5     1     3 Rapid_Progressor
15:  5     3     4    No-progressor
16:  5     3     5    No-progressor
```